# Union can't match two string columns

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

I have the following query.

```
var test = await DbContext.StorageAdjustments
    .Where(a => a.StorageId == id && a.TimeStamp >= start)
    .Select(a => new StorageUpdateModel
    {
        TimeStamp = a.TimeStamp,
        Change = a.Volume,
        Product = a.Product.Name,
        UpdateType = StorageUpdateType.Adjustment,
        Notes = "BOL",
    })
    .Union(DbContext.StorageTrucks
        .Where(t => t.StorageId == id && t.TimeStamp >= start)
        .Select(t => new StorageUpdateModel
        {
            TimeStamp = t.TimeStamp,
            Change = t.Volume,
            Product = "xxx",
            UpdateType = StorageUpdateType.Truck,
            Notes = "BOL",
        }))
    .ToListAsync();
```

But it throws an exception.

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'Unable to translate set operation when matching columns on both sides have different store types.'
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.SqlExpressions.SelectExpression.ApplySetOperation(SetOperationType setOperationType, SelectExpression select2, Boolean distinct)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalQueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.TranslateUnion(ShapedQueryExpression source1, ShapedQueryExpression source2)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression node)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryCompilationContext.CreateQueryExecutor[TResult](Expression query)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.<>c__DisplayClass12_0`1.<ExecuteAsync>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.CompiledQueryCache.GetOrAddQuery[TResult](Object cacheKey, Func`1 compiler)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.ExecuteAsync[TResult](Expression query, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryProvider.ExecuteAsync[TResult](Expression expression, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable`1.GetAsyncEnumerator(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredCancelableAsyncEnumerable`1.GetAsyncEnumerator()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.<ToListAsync>d__65`1.MoveNext()
   at Pegasus.Pages.Transloading.StorageLocations.DetailsModel.<OnGetAsync>d__15.MoveNext() in D:\Users\jwood\source\repos\Railtrax\Pegasus\Pages\Transloading\StorageLocations\Details.cshtml.cs:line 65
```

If I change `Product = a.Product.Name,` to `Product = "xxx"`, it works without an exception.

I really don't understand this. `a.Product.Name` is defined in the database as `(nvarchar(120), not null)`. Does anyone know why `Union()` can't combine two string columns, or how to coherce them to the same type?

Comment: Is product name defined as nvarchar(120) in both tables? The error suggests otherwise. You can also cast "product" to guarantee a same type. Execute the query in SSMS to test it.

Comment: @DouadyRabbit: No, you can see from the code that the second table is using a string literal and not any column.

Comment: yes, you mentioned that in your question. Your real query doesn't have a literal, it has a column name, that's why I asked, anyways this seems to be a bug on the version of EF that you are using, https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/19129

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like a change to address the underlying issue was being considered for version 3.0 on [GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/16298).

I don't understand why it wasn't considered important enough to implement even in version 7.0.

It makes it extremely difficult to workaround such an issue with the only valid workaround being to perform the `Union()` on the client side, along with its obvious performance disadvantages.

#### Update

There was one workaround by using `Product = Convert.ToString(a.Product.Name)` and it actually works for me. However, it seems to be using `NVARCHAR(MAX)` and people [posted comments](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/19129#issuecomment-714292970) that it can cause resource problems.